# Erlang Beginner: Find Perimeter?

Tags: erlang

I am learning Erlang and was attempting problem mentioned [here](http://www.erlang.org/course/exercises.html#simple), as

```
3. Write a function mathStuff:perimeter(Form) which computes the perimeter of different forms. Form can be one of:

    {square,Side}
    {circle,Radius}
    {triangle,A,B,C}
```

So, my solution to this is

```
-module(mathStuff).
-export([perimeter/1]).

perimeter(Form) ->
        case element(1, Form) of
                square          -> io:format("perimeter for square is ~p~n", [4*element(2, Form)]);
                circle          -> io:format("perimeter for circle is ~p~n", [2*math:pi()*element(2, Form)]);
                triangle        -> io:format("perimeter for triangle ~p~n", [element(2, Form) + element(3, Form) + element(4, Form)])
        end.
~
```

and when I run I get

```
38> c("mathStuff.erl").              
{ok,mathStuff}
39> mathStuff:perimeter({circle, 2}).
perimeter for circle is 12.566370614359172
ok
40> mathStuff:perimeter({rectangle, 2}).
** exception error: no case clause matching rectangle
     in function  mathStuff:perimeter/1 (mathStuff.erl, line 5)
41> mathStuff:perimeter({square, 2}).   
perimeter for square is 8
ok
42> mathStuff:perimeter({traingle, 1, 2, 3}).
** exception error: no case clause matching traingle
     in function  mathStuff:perimeter/1 (mathStuff.erl, line 5)
43> mathStuff:perimeter({triangle, 1, 2, 3}).
perimeter for triangle 6
ok
```

but this is incorrect since I can also do

```
44> mathStuff:perimeter({triangle, 1, 2, 3, 4}).
perimeter for triangle 6
ok
45>
```

What is a better way to approach this problem, how can I be more specific about type and arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the first error is that you are not matching `rectangle` in your `case ... end` expression, so it fails to match anything. Unlike most imperative languages, a `case` expression in a functional language is generally required to match at least one clause -- otherwise, what value should the expression evaluate to?

A more idiomatic way of solving this problem involves [pattern matching](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions) at the function head, like so:

```
perimeter({square, Side}) ->
    io:format("perimeter for square is ~p~n", [4*Side]);
...
perimeter({triangle, A, B, C}) ->
    io:format("perimeter for triangle ~p~n", [A + B + C]).
```

Note that the function clauses are separated using `;`, with the last clause being terminated with `.`.

In essence, instead of manually selecting fields from the tuple with `element/2`, Erlang allows you to "unpack" the tuple using pattern matching. This is, in my opinion, one of the greatest benefits of using a functional language with algebraic data types.

Incidentally, the reason that you got a correct result even for an erroneous call like `perimeter({triangle, 1, 2, 3, 4})` is that you *didn't* use pattern matching, but instead manually selected the relevant fields of the tuple. You never checked that the tuple wasn't too long! Pattern matching performs a kind of input validation as a side-effect, because an expression like:

```
{A, B, C} = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Is guaranteed to fail with a match error.

Comment: Thank you @Martin, this is really key to understand Pattern Matching.